# Dynamically adding click event to checkbox, only works for first checkbox JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

So I am working with a couple ascx with different checkbox areas on each control.
I originally used

```
 $('[type=checkbox]').click ( function(){ code });
```

and it did the job, At first. But when i added another control, also using checkboxes, the function was firing for the other checkboxes as well so i upgraded the js to

```
 $('#chck').click(function(){ code });
```

But with this, it only fires an event for the first checkbox in that list.. how can i get it to fire for all clicks?

I have also tried this:

```
 $('#chck').each(function(){ $(this).click({ function() { code }); });
```

and this only worked for the first one as well

here is my ascx page example:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="contacts" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="chck" />
                    </td>
                  .....
                 </tr>
             </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
```

and here is my JS code segment

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#chck").each(function () {
           $(this).click(function () { onchange($(this)); });
       });
    });
    function onchange(checkbox) {
    // adds contact to list
    }
```

Comment: You should never have multiple of an id. Use a class for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`id`s must be unique.  Use a class instead:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="chck" />
```

```
$('.chck').click(function(){ code });
```

Comment: yep, that'll fix it.. i figured since it was in a repeater n it didn't give a warning or an error, that it was ok.

Comment: You can do all kinds of things in `.net` without compilation errors/warnings that will produce completely invalid html.

Answer (score 1):

See `using same ids for multiple elems` on a `same page is invalid.`

`IDs should be unique to each element. When this happens browser only selects first of it.`

To overcome this issue one must change `id` to `class`. So you `have to do same thing with your markup change id to class`:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="chck" /> // <----change id to class for every input
```

and now your script should be:

```
$('.chck').each(function(){ //<-----use '.' notation for class selectors 
     $(this).click(function() { 
         onchange($(this));
     }); 
});
```