# Hover in each checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, checkbox, laravel-blade

**Updated this question, because my previous code made a conflict with bootstrap**

Hi I'm trying to make a hover in each checkbox. What I now have is that the hover occurs in each checkbox. When I click around the checkbox then you see a dropdownlist. But when I click away from the dropdownlist. Then the caret arrow should go away, but unfortunately it doesn't. I have also recorded myself to show you more clearly what I actually want:

**Updated the video also, because my updated code displays the checkbox differently in the browser**

link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i6-T9wjNZY8&feature=youtu.be

Here is the code that I currently have, which lives in index.blade.php :

```
  @extends('user._layouts.user')

@section('content')
<style>
      .dropdown .caret{
            display:none;
      }

      .dropdown:hover .caret,  .dropdown.opened .caret{
            display:inline-block;
      }
</style>
<script>
    var resetSel = function(){

    };

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('dropdown').on('click', function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            $('.dropdown.opened').removeClass('opened');
        });

          $('.dropdown').click(function(e){

            var $this = $(this);

            $('.dropdown.opened').removeClass('opened');

             if(!$this.hasClass('opened'))
                $this.addClass('opened');

            //alert($check.attr('checked'));
        });

        $('.check').click(function(e){
             e.stopPropagation();
        });


});
</script>

<script>
function toggle(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('check');
  for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}
</script>

@include('user._layouts.template_search')
<h1>Offerte overzicht</h1>
{{--link_to_route('user.orders.create', 'Create new Order')--}} 
@if (count($orders)) 
<ul>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1">STATUS</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">offerte naam</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">klant</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">bedrag</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">old delete</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">Check all
            <br>
            <div class="btn-group">
<div class="dropdown">
    <button id="selDelete" type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <input id="check1" type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" class="check">
        <span class="caret-hover"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="selDelete" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    @foreach($orders as $order)
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <li>
                @if ($order->status=='not submitted')
                <div class="statusRed"></div>
                @elseif ($order->status=='pending')
                <div class="statusOrange"></div>
                @else 
                <div class="statusGreen"></div>
                @endif  
            </li>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <li>
                {{--as a third parameter we need to pass in the orderId, because it needs to be fed to
                our actual user.orders.edit route. --}}
                {{link_to_route('user.orders.edit', $order->order_name, array($order->id))}}    
            </li>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <li>
                {{$order->client['companyName']}}
            </li>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <li>
                &#8364;{{$order->price}}
            </li>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <li>
                {{Form::open(array('route'=>array('user.orders.destroy',$order->id),
                'method'=>'delete','class'=>'destroy'))}}

                {{Form::submit('Delete', array('class' => 'btn btn-default'))}}
                {{Form::close()}}
            </li>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1">
            <li>
                <!--ik kan blade niet gebruiken, want hij laat me mijn checkbox altijd op checked staan.-->
                 <div class="dropdown">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle selDelete" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <input id="check1" name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" class="check" >
                        <span class="caret-hover caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="selDelete" role="menu">
                        <li><a href= "{{ route('user.orders.destroy',array( $order->id )) }}" data-method="delete" >Deletey</a></li>

                    </ul>   
                </div>
            </li>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
</ul>
@endif

@stop
```

Gladly I'm waiting for your response. Anyway thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have used an id 'selDelete' around multiple items.  Consider using a class:

```
class = selDelete
```

in place of any tags where you have put:

```
id = selDelete
```

And similarly, be sure to switch any references to:

```
#selDelete
```

into:

```
.selDelete
```

I believe that may solve your problem, check that before anything else, hope that helps :)

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer I have tried your solution, but I still get the hover at multiple boxes (except the first one). I made a screenshot what I actually mean: link http://i.imgur.com/pinaBRg.png  (for some reason you don't see my mouse when I had made the screenshot) I did what you told me, but maybe I had changed the code the wrong way. This is what I have done now:  link: http://pastebin.com/rsMyns7U

Comment: shoot, sorry I couldn't help you with that.  I'll take a look, I had hoped it would be an easy answer.

Comment: Ok, take a look at this answer here:  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300183/dynamically-adding-click-event-to-checkbox-only-works-for-first-checkbox-jquery) ; it's basically redundant to my answer, BUT, your symptoms are nearly identical, and, the OP responds that his problem was solved after switching ID's to classes.  I know that's not helpful, but it makes me think maybe there's some other buried css or javascript that's affecting it

Comment: Do you have a demo version of this anywhere I could play with?  I think if I had a bit of time to play around with the page inspector, I'd like to think I could crack the case

Comment: Hi Eleanor it was indeed some other buried css or javascript from bootstrap (font-end framework). Because of that I have changed the code. So maybe you or someone else knows the solution now. I have also tried to put the code on jsfiddle, but for some reason I can't  open a dropdownlist if I click around the checkbox. If you stil want to see it, then you can find it here link: http://jsfiddle.net/yomacho/9Lo8wjss/

Comment: So, sorry, did you figure it out?  I am still puzzled myself, but I did look over the jsfiddle you provided

Comment: No, I haven't figured it out. To be honest I really don't know how to fix this hehe. The jsfiddle that I gave, doesn't work properly. Because you can't see a dropdownlist if you click around the checkbox. In the video I had shown that, if you click around the checkbox you see a dropdownlist.

Comment: Yea, sorry, I am frustrated with myself I couldn't figure it out, I'd have to do some more investigation, probably don't have enough time to do that, though